# Input field not submitting anything - React

Tags: html, http, reactjs

I'm working on a project where the front end is powered by React. I'm not even sure if this is relevant (maybe the problem lies in another obvious place), but since I've been able to make everything work without React so far, it would be fair to guess that it's my relationship with React that is resulting in this error.

In my React template (?) I added this most simple piece of code, that is rendered inside a form:

```
if (this.state.indexColumns['0'].show === true) {
    cols.splice(xKey + idxMod, 0, (
        <DataTableStaticCell key={'index-' + k}>
            {content}
        </DataTableStaticCell>
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value={indexId}  />
    ));
} else {
    cols.splice(xKey + idxMod + 1, 0, (
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value={indexId}  />
    ));
}
```

When I check using developer tools in browsers, everything is rendered correctly and the field is there, it has the correct value, is located inside a form like it's supposed to be.
Rendered:

```
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="1" data-reactid=".0.2.0.0.1.0.0.$2.2.0.$2.$0.$0.$0.$rows.0.0.2.0.0.1.$0.1">
```

Now, whenever I post my form, no data is submitted from this field at all. I use Chrome developer tools to catch the form send request (any better methods?) and it does not appear there.

I've tried everything I could think of so far: visible field, not-prefixed-value field, different types of input, different names and such... Some stupid idiotic mistake is ruining my life at the moment, been stuck with this for two days now. I can't even believe that myself.

Appreciate your help :)

EDIT: Form handling:

```
getFormData: function (validate) {
    var invalid = false;
    if (validate) {
        invalid |= !this.state.form.validate();

        if (invalid) {
            logger.warn(this.state.form.errors().asData());
        }
    }

    var formData = _.extend({}, this.state.form.cleanedData);

    var dataTableKeys = this.findLayoutKeysByType('data_table');
    dataTableKeys.forEach(function (tableKey) {
        var ref = this.refs['dataTable' + tableKey];

    }.bind(this));

    return [!invalid, formData];
},
```

EDIT 2: I should add that `<DataTableStaticCell>` was already in place before I started working on the project and also contains an `<input>` field, which is rendered like this for example:

```
<input type="text" value="" data-reactid=".0.2.0.0.1.0.0.$2.2.0.$2.$0.$0.$0.$rows.0.0.2.0.0.1.$0.$0.1.0">
```

That is the main reason I started with this approach. Are there any fundamental differences between my data flow and with the example presented later?

Comment: Where is the form handling logic?

Comment: Is indexId coming from state or is it just a local variable?

Comment: @Moogs I updated the original post.

Comment: @Jeff It comes from state. Could that pose an issue?

Comment: No, having it state does not cause an issue. But that means it is available to you when uploading the data. And i'd get it from state, if at all possible,

Comment: @makaveli, looking at the updates, I think you should change your approach. You are following a standard MVC approach and not a React approach. In React, each element should update state when it's value changes. State is then used to build the values to send to the API.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your input. Could you give me a simple example of how I should restructure the data flow?

Comment: If you haven't gone through it already, The React tutorial is a great place to start. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html. If you've used that, I'd look for other React samples/tutorials. Sorry, but there isn't enough code here for me to provide more of an answer.